# Devo criptografar a senha antes de enviá-la ao servidor?

Tags: segurança, criptografia

Estou em dúvida se devo criptografar uma senha antes de enviá-la ao servidor, e no servidor salvar o hash no banco, ou se devo criptografar somente no servidor...

Comment: É uma boa pergunta. Acredito que a resposta curta seria: "Criptografe no servidor, envie sobre uma conexão HTTPS". Penso isso porque tudo que está no cliente é inseguro, então o próprio algoritmo de criptografia pode ser alterado no cliente.
Não criei uma resposta sobre isso porque minha opinião, sem embasamento ou provas, apenas "poluiria" as respostas. Deixo aqui para debate :D

Comment: Perguntei sobre isso no [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195710/are-plaintext-post-payloads-over-https-safe), foram-me apontadas algumas respostas. Não é um assunto muito trivial.

Comment: O TLS é seguro, supondo que as autoridades sejam. Você tem o Expected-CT e o também havia o antigo HPKP que garantem ainda mais segurança quanto à um CA corrupto. Você também deve usar o HSTS, para impedir um downgrade para HTTP, assim o site só pode ser acessado usando HTTPS, inclusive pode usar o preload e enviar o site à uma lista, assim os novos navegadores já sabem que o seu site só entra por HTTPS. O TLS garante "perfect forward secrecy", já que usa chaves únicas a cada conexões e as chaves são destruídas após o uso, claro se você usar o ECDHE (ou DHE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma diferença entre encriptar (proteger a comunicação entre o client-servidor; exemplo de algoritmos: AES, ChaCha20, Salsa20, DES, 3DES...) e derivar (impedir a descoberta do valor inicial e conversão de senhas para chaves, exemplos: PBKDF2, Bcrypt, Scrypt, Argon2).

---

Existem vantagens entre derivar no lado do cliente. Um deles é evitar DoS no seu servidor, você não leu errado.

O que ocorre é que os algoritmos de PBKDF (Password Based Key Derivation Function) são extremamente dependentes do custo computacional, quanto mais melhor. Uma carteira de criptomoeda offline pode se dar o luxo de demorar 10 segundos, usando todos os núcleos do processador e mais de 8GB de RAM, apenas para derivar uma senha. Uma encriptação de disco por senha (primeiro converte a senha em chave, usando tal derivação, para então encriptar) também pode levar alguns minutos para derivar, levando o dispositivo ao extremo, já que isso deve ser feito apenas uma vez.

Entretanto, sites não pode dar esse luxo. O seu site deve responder rápido, geralmente em menos de 1 segundo. Deve ainda responder vários usuários. Por isso, não pode usar 100% da capacidade do servidor apenas para essa atividade, então convém reduzir a dificuldade computacional.

Por isso você pode combinar os dois lados. O seu cliente faz parte do trabalho e você faz a outra parte. O seu cliente pode usar o PBKDF2 (disponível nativamente no WebCrypto API) e o seu servidor usa este resultado e deriva com Argon2, então compara. É importante notar que o seu servidor deve derivar o resultado derivado, **se não você está armazenando uma senha igualmente em texto-claro.**

A derivação exige um salt, que deve ser único. No caso do cliente, o salt pode ser o e-mail, ele será único, mas determinístico, se o e-mail não for alterado. Mas, se a senha for alterada ele irá usar o mesmo salt, então haverá duas senhas para o mesmo salt, o que não é "perfeito". A outra forma é fazer um consulta de qual o salt do usuário, mas isso também pode revelar se ele está registrado ou não. Um outro maleficio são usuários com computadores lentos, ou smartphones, que podem demorar mais para efetuar o login.

*O LastPass usa a técnica de derivar no lado do cliente.*

---

Já encriptar não faz muito sentido. O TLS já faz isso, então basta usar o HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

Criptografia e hashing são coisas diferentes. Normalmente ao fazer hashing de uma senha, você adiciona "salts", que são itens extras adicionados à senha antes de fazer o hash para ter uma segurança maior.

Por exemplo você pode salvar a senha do usuário como `data_cadastro + senha + id` e fazer um hash disso. Quando for validar a senha, você pega a data de cadastro, id e concatena com a senha do usuário que foi informada, e compara os dois hashes.

Isso fornece uma camada extra de segurança e nenhum cliente sabe quais são seus métodos de hashing.

Se você fizer isso no front, é fácil para o cliente descobrir como é feito.

Acredito que deve ficar no back-end mesmo.

Lembrando que por HTTPS, as informações já são enviadas pro servidor criptografadas, por meio de SSL. Se isso era um dos motivos para o questionamento, o HTTPS já cobre ;)